# Problem linking React App to MongoDB Atlas Database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have created a react app that needs user registration and authentication. I have written all the code to link it to my MongoDB Atlas, but when I click "Register User", after the user has put it their name and password, what I see is "POST http://localhost:3000/register 404 (Not Found). What does this mean and how do I clear it?

Comment: 404 means the webserver on localhost doesn't know what to do with a POST request to the  `/register` URI.  You will need to check the configuration of the webserver, or edit the question to add the relevant bits of the configuration